# Fill down a formula in VBA only where there is data in the column before

Tags: excel, vba

apologies as I am new here. I've done a lot of searching and am failing to find answers and I am losing my hair.
I have data that is broken up in blocks of rows.  Here's an example:

Group1
August 4
Sam
Bob
Rosie

Group 2
March 13
Carl
Jon

**I want to insert a column and add a formula in that column everywhere there is data in the first column. The length and placement of code blocks vary. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!**

Here's what I have so far but it only fills down the first block:

````
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(TRIM(RC[-1]),participants.xlsx!R2C1:R1000C4,3,FALSE)"
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("B8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)) ```
````

Comment: Why do you need to insert a column?

Comment: There is some data to the right that is important as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the areas (this code assumes the cells do not contain formulas):

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    r.Offset(, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
    r.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=row()+1"
Next r

End Sub
```

Starting data is orange, the code adds the green.

[image]

Editted to insert a column. You could just a column at the beginning once if that meets your needs.